# SKMaps and ViaPoints/WayPoints

Tags: ios, swift, skmaps

I have questions regarding skmap sdk functionality.

After creating a route and starting the navigation process, is there anyway of capturing the `waypoint`/`viapoint` that you are currently directed towards? After calculating a route, it seems `routeInformation.viaPointsOnRoute` is empty. Does `calculateRoute(route)` automatically generate a list of `viaPoints`? In the `SKNavigationDelegate` Protocol Reference I see the following event functions :

```
– routingService:didEnterViaPointArea:
– routingService:didReachViaPointWithIndex:
– routingService:didExitViaPointArea:
```

However, these methods never seem to be called. Not sure if they are only called if `ViaPoints` are programmatically added.

Also when the routeService fires the currentAdvice and nextAdvice methods, the SKRouteAvice location appear to be empty as well.

Is there anyway someone could provide me with a simple example of how to create and capture the current `waypoint` position and the next `waypoint` position while in navigation? Essentially, I am trying to calculate the direction from the current location to the next `waypoint`.

Below is rough example of my route and navigation initiation code:

```
//Created Route
let route: SKRouteSettings = SKRouteSettings()
route.routeMode = SKRouteMode.Pedestrian
route.startCoordinate = coordinateCurrent!
route.destinationCoordinate = coordinateDestination!
route.shouldBeRendered = true 
SKRoutingService.sharedInstance().calculateRoute(r oute)

//Start Navigation
let navSettings: SKNavigationSettings = SKNavigationSettings()
navSettings.navigationType = SKNavigationType.Simulation
navSettings.distanceFormat = SKDistanceFormat.MilesFeet
navSettings.viaPointNotificationDistance=1
self.mapView!.settings.displayMode = SKMapDisplayMode.Mode3D
navSettings.transportMode = SKTransportMode.Pedestrian
SKRoutingService.sharedInstance().startNavigationW ithSettings(navSettings)

//Start Postioner Service
SKPositionerService.sharedInstance().delegate = self
SKPositionerService.sharedInstance().startLocation Update()
routeInfo.viaPointsOnRoute

func routingService(routingService: SKRoutingService!, didChangeNextAdvice nextAdvice: SKRouteAdvice, isLastAdvice:Bool)
{
    log(String(nextAdvice.location))
}

func routingService(routingService: SKRoutingService!, didChangeCurrentAdvice currentAdvice: SKRouteAdvice, isLastAdvice:Bool)
{
    log(String(currentAdvice.location))
}

func routingService(routingService: SKRoutingService!,
                    didUpdateViaPointsInformation viaPoints: [AnyObject]!)
{
    log("VIA INFO: " + String(viaPoints))
}

func routingService(routingService: SKRoutingService!,
                    didEnterViaPointArea index: Int32)
{
    log("ENTER VIA: " + String(index))
}

func routingService(routingService: SKRoutingService!,
                    didExitViaPointArea index: Int32)
{
    log("EXIT VIA: " + String(index))
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I think that first we have to clarify the terminology.

viaPoint or waypoint (the skobbler/telenav SDK uses the viaPoint terminology) would be a point on the route that is explicitly declared as a "viaPoint". These points are added at route calculation time (by passing an array of [viaPoints](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.5.1/Classes/SKRouteSettings.html#//api/name/viaPoints) in the route settings) or during navigation with the [addViaPoint](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.5.1/Classes/SKRoutingService.html#//api/name/addViaPoint:afterViaPointWithID:) API.

These viaPoints will be monitored by the SDK and you'll receive the didEnterViaPointArea, didReachViaPointWithIndex and didExitViaPointArea callbacks.

I believe that you're using the term waypoint by describing a "junction" or "point requiring an advice" along the route - these would mostly correspond to the "route coordinates" provided by the SDK (see the [routeCoordinationsForRouteWithID](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.5.1/Classes/SKRoutingService.html#//api/name/routeCoordinatesForRouteWithId:) API). These route coordinates are not explicitly surfaced by the SDK - you don't get any explicit information about these points but only indirect notifications in the form of advices ("In 200 meters turn right onto Main Street").

What the turn by turn engine provides you is exactly the "direction" between 2 such coordinates (in the form of an advice: "carry straight on", "turn right", "turn left"). See the documentation regarding how the advices are created for more details ([here](http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/advisor-support-text-to-speech-scout-audio/) and [here](http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/advisor-support-text-to-speech-faq/))

Maybe the skobbler/Telenav team can provide you better advice if you could describe your end goal (what use case you are trying to achieve).